# How to plot a chart in windows form

Tags: c#, graph, charts

I have data in the form shown below.  I want to display the data in such a way that time (the "No column name" column in the figure) should be along the Y-axis and testiD and queryId in the X-axis. I need it in such a way that items with same testId should be grouped (in the X-axis) and the corresponding time should be displayed (Y-axis)

here is the code I use, it does not work as I expected.

```
protected internal Chart GenerateChart(DataTable dtChartDataSource,Chart chart,int intType )
{      
    ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea() { Name = "ChartArea" };
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
    chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
    string series = string.Empty;
    if (dtChartDataSource != null)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dtChartDataSource.Columns)
        {
            if (chart.Series.FindByName(dc.ColumnName) == null)
            {
                series = dc.ColumnName[1].ToString();
                chart.Series.Add(series);
                chart.Series[series].ChartType = (SeriesChartType)intType;
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
            {
                double dataPoint = 0;
                double.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);
                DataPoint objDataPoint = new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "series", YValues = new double[] { dataPoint } };
                chart.Series[series].Points.Add(dataPoint);
            }
        }
    }
    return chart;
}
```

I could get my requirement done by below code.

public Chart fnTestChart(Chart chart, DataTable dt) 
        {
            DataTable dtUniqueCols = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Test ID");
            chart.ChartAreas.Add("area");
            chart.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            //chart.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            //chart.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Interval = 1;

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtUniqueCols.Rows)

        {
            chart.Series.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            chart.Series[dr[0].ToString()].Points.AddXY(dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString());
        }
        return chart;

    }
```

[image: Data in sql server]

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR)].

Comment: What about your code doesn't work?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain *in which way* it doesn't work--what results are you getting and how they differ from the intended results? Include any error messages you receive.

Comment: Thank you for showing the interest to resolve the issue. I could get my requrement done by below code

Answer (score -3):

You can use many different libraries, to achieve this goal.

Ex:  ([Visblox](http://www.visiblox.com/))

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  In this case, perhaps show an example of how to make plots using Visblox